# safari webkit file upload control

Tags: xcode, webview

I have a safari webkit inside my mobile app which renders a webpage. The webpage has File upload option.
 when I click on it 3 options are shown as in screenshot. I am trying to make the safari kit to only allow Camera capture and hide Upload already existing files.  Is there any safari permission which I can remove to configuration that hide the options of upload from files.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym5Ca.png)